# CSS tricks - Get rid of the top and bottom spaces between the text and div border

Tags: html, css

I have a text inside a div. All I want is to get rid of the top and bottom spaces between the text and div border. Could you please help me.

HTML:

```
<div id="text">APPLE</div>
```

CSS:

```
#text {
float:left;
font-size:3em;
color: black;
}
```

Comment: is this you want http://jsfiddle.net/zsrqdyxd/?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for but the white "space" is actually part of the character glyph. It's reserved for descenders such as can be found in lower case letters - http://jsfiddle.net/feea67oc/

Comment: not exactly. if you even set padding to 0, there is a space between the text and the div border. I want to get rid of that space.

Comment: You can't, generally, you can play with `line-height` (http://jsfiddle.net/feea67oc/1/) but there is no magic setting that will work for all fonts, font-sizes or browsers.

Comment: not clear what the problem is...make a screenshot of the issue....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll need to play around with the `line-height`
http://jsfiddle.net/ysqs6veu/

For simplicity I've used percentage in the height so this should work for all your font sizes.

```
#text {
    float:left;
    font-size:3em;
    line-height: 65%;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: WOW! -1 for what exactly? no comments?

Comment: Because it doesn't work consistently. You've used a **magic number** - http://jsfiddle.net/ysqs6veu/1/

Comment: Oh ok, so the part where i say "you will have to play around with the line-height" part doesn't make sense?

Comment: Adjusting the percentage to fit his font, will then make it work consistently with that specific font no?

Answer (score 0):

> Use " Line-height property" . it will work.

```
#text {
  float: left;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 23px;  /*Change the value according to your choice*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twy with `em` unit. It is relative to the font-size of the element. Try with -

```
#text {
  float:left;
  font-size:3em;
  color: black;
  line-height: .7em;
}
```

It will automatically calculate depending on the font size.

Comment: For this type of conditions we have to use less or sass i think.

Comment: Possibly but It's doubltful even then it would be consistent across all browsers, fonts etc. I think the OP is looking for a "one-size-fits-all" solution and there just isn't one AFAIK. Plus **text-nodes:bad**

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also...

```
#inner{
     margin: -8% 0px -8% 0px;
}

<div id="text">
   <div id="inner">APPLE</div>
</div>
```